# Mongodb: Sorting a integer field where 0,nil is grater than any positive integer

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a table Job and there is a field max_limit. max_limit can be any positive integer or 0 or nil. I need to sort it in such a way that documents with 0 or nil comes after any document with positive integer. Similarly if I sort it in descending order, documents with 0 or nil should come at top.

How to write query for this considering we may have large about of data to sort so will be using indexing for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to sort at mongo level or code level. If at mongo level then you need sort and update ?

Comment: I want a mongodb query and just to read not to update.